# using an older version of react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm following a ReactJS tutorial in which the tutor is using class-based components (not hooks at that point) and react-router-dom  which is still using render and component (without using the 'element' keyword)..

So, I found how to downgrade the react-router-dom:

```
npm install --save react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

I'm not sure if it's the accurate version in which I can use render/component instead of element, plus, I'm not sure if I need also an older version of create-react-app, and if so, to what version and how I do it?

Regards!

P.S
I have tried to follow the tutorial after installing react-router-dom@5.2.0 (and maintaining npx create-react-app as is), but I got so many errors:

> 2tiny-invariant.js:12 Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not
> use `<Route>` outside a `<Router>`
> at invariant (tiny-invariant.js:12:1)
> at Route.js:35:1
> at updateContextConsumer (react-dom.development.js:21207:1)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21652:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
> at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1) react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the
> `<Router.Consumer>` component:
>
> at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40759:29) at div
> at App
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn more about error boundaries. logCapturedError @
> react-dom.development.js:18687 react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught
> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use  outside a 
> at invariant (tiny-invariant.js:12:1)
> at Route.js:35:1
> at updateContextConsumer (react-dom.development.js:21207:1)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21652:1)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
> at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
> at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
> at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
> at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)

Comment: `npm install --save react-router-dom@5.2.0` is correct for installing v5.2.0 specifically. What version do you *actually* need? The error is saying you are using RRD components ***outside*** a router.

Comment: I have no idea. As the course is out-of-date, the only thing I can tell is that it's a version which uses keywords such as 'render' and 'component' but not 'element'.

Comment: Yeah, so anything from probably v3 to v4/5. This tutorial doesn't go over what dependencies need to be installed? Why even use such an old and outdated tutorial? RRD, for both v4/5 and for v6 are quite well documented and include examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess it's for the sake of consistency. As he moves on, he moves onto hooks.

Comment: If they are using hooks then it's most certainly RRDv5. I'd suggest just installing the latest v5 version, `npm i react-router-dom@5` which should install v5.3.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try version npm install --save react-router-dom@4.3.1 –
Here is the sample code for it:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./Main";
import Menu from "./Menu";

import "./styles.css";

export const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={props => <Main {...props} />} />
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Menu} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, rootElement);
```